# powershell error :cannot find path because it does not exist

Tags: powershell, filepath

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yY06C.png)

i ran below script in power shell and its giving cannot find path as it does not exist .although i have specified correct path .
Please can anybody suggest what mistake i am making and how to correct this ? i have attached a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ihJ6N.png) as well

```
$folder="D:\Patch\data";             
$txtFile="D:\Patch\Export.txt"; 
$pattern="\1+.+";              

get-content $txtFile | %{

    if($_ -match $pattern)
    {
        mkdir "$folder\$_";
    }
}
```

Comment: it states that the file "D:\Patch\Export.txt" does not exist. you can verify if a file/folder exists with `Test-Path -Path $txtFile` which I suppose will also give an error? please run that and make sure using the file explorer that the file does exist (and does not have a typo?). if the error persists list all files using `Get-ChildItem -Path "D:\Patch"` to get a list of files in that very folder.

Comment: Looks like missing permission to access the file. Try running ISE as admin, does it work ? If it does, you might have the permissions to that path set to administrators (so UAC would prevent execution from a non administrative shell)

Comment: @guentherSchmitz the script is running without any error but folders are not getting created . please check below script and let know what is the error .$folder="D:\Patch\data";             /path where folder needs to be created/ 
$txtFile="D:\Patch\Export.txt";  /file where all names of servers are written/
              

get-content $txtFile | %{

    if($_ -match "^(\d+) (\w+)$")
    {
        mkdir "$folder\$_";
    }
}

Comment: @DeekshaKhare did you verify the txt file exists? Did you try running the script in an elevated shell?

Comment: yes that .txt file exist it was named incorrectly so i corrected that .thanks to ur command Get-ChildItem -Path "D:\Patch"   .....but the problem is folder is not getting created.please see the screensot which  i have attached again

Comment: What is that pattern supposed to do? It starts with `\1` which is a backreference to an _undefined_ numbered capturing group 1... Please explain what you are trying to do there and as aside, do not post images of code ans error messages, but insert that in your question as [formatted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work) text

Comment: PLEASE, do not post images of code/errors/data. why? because the text in those images is part of the diagnostic process ... and having to squint at or re-enter what you already have as text is ... rather thoughtless on your part.